# using tow with in laravel elequent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, one-to-many

in using laravel 7
and let say i have three table

```
+───────────+────────────────+────────+
| products  | product_units  | units  |  
+───────────+────────────────+────────+
| id        | id             | id     |  
| name      | product_id     | name   |  
| ect       | unit_id        |        |  
+───────────+────────────────+────────+
```

and inside Product model i have this method

```
public function get_unit_relations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product_unit','product_id','id');
}
```

and inside product_units i have this method

```
public function get_unit_id()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Unit','id','unit_id');
}
```

now if i want to return product i can do this ..

```
return Product::find(1);
```

so i gat this return

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
    }
]
```

and if i want the return to have a relation i can do this code

```
return Product::find(1)->with('get_unit_relations');
```

this will return json like this ..

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "get_unit_relations": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "unit_id": 2,
                "product_id": 1,
                "barcode": "455",
                "smallest_unit_relation": 12,
                "price": 12,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

my question now is how can i use other ->with with the `get_unit_relations`
when return the product->with('get_unit_relations')

```
public function get_unit_id()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Unit','id','unit_id');
}
```

to get result like this ..

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "get_unit_relations": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "unit_id": 2,
                "product_id": 1,
                "barcode": "455",
                "smallest_unit_relation": 12,
                "price": 12,
                'get_unit_id':[ // how can i get the result with this method also to access the name of the unit
                    {
                        id:1,
                        name:'unit name',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

what i want is return the product and hasMany product_units and hasOne unit to access the name of the unit 
thanks a lot ..

Comment: I guess `with('get_unit_relations','get_unit_relations.get_unit_id')->...` will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution to add the `get_unit_id` like this

```
public function get_unit_relations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product_unit','product_id','id')->with('get_unit_id');
}
```

and its worked thanks everyone ..